# CSS rotation text-only inside <th> tag

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-transforms

I am trying to rotate the text -90 degrees inside *some* `th` cells:

```css
.th-vert {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>0000</th>
      <th class="th-vert">0000</th>
      <th class="th-vert">0000</th>
      <th class="th-vert">0000</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that my browser appears to be rotating the whole `th` element... meaning that its width seems to turn into it's new height... notice below how the `th` is appearing *beneath* the row that comes after it:

[image]

I would like it so that the `th` simply adjusts its size / shape so that it accommodates the vertical text, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode):

```css
.th-vert {
 writing-mode:vertical-rl;
 padding:0 1.25em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>0000</th>
      <th class="th-vert">0000</th>
      <th class="th-vert">0000</th>
      <th class="th-vert">0000</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

another example http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EKQKBe